# Action method not being invoked

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am having an issue with `<h:commandButton>` and `<a4j:commandButton>` in a form with a `<rich:pickList>` the action fires fine if I remove the `<rich:pickList>` but the pickList needs to be there.

Is this a known issue and if so is there a work around for it?

This is what the code looks like

```
    <rich:modalPanel id="editAlbumPanel" width="580" height="255">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="Edit Album #{mainBean.album.title}" styleClass="modal_header_txt" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <a4j:commandButton id="closeEditAlbum" image="images/close.png"
                onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('editAlbumPanel');" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <h:form id="editAlbumForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Genres" styleClass="descript"/>
            <rich:pickList value="#{mainBean.selectedGenres}" copyControlLabel="Add"
                fastMoveControlsVisible="false">
                <f:selectItems value="#{mainBean.genreSelect}"/>
            </rich:pickList>
            <h:outputText value="Explicit Lyrics: " styleClass="descript"/>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="spacer" value="#{mainBean.album.explicitLyrics}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <div align="right">
            <a4j:commandButton value="Apply Changes" action="#{mainBean.editAlbumA}"
                oncomplete="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('editAlbumPanel');"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Cancel" styleClass="spacer" onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('editAlbumPanel');"/>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

#### EDIT Extra Information

The action method is called if and only if the right hand side of the pick list is empty, aka the user selects no options

Comment: Are you sure that you have just one h:form? And the h:form encapsulates all command buttons or links?

Comment: there is more than 1 h:form but they are all placed outside of each other but still within the f:view. The thing is if i remove the picklist it works fine

Comment: why do you want seperate h:forms? Cant you have just one h:form to enclose all command components?

Comment: it's the way I have always worked with modal panels and it's always worked, till now. I place the modalpanel outside the main form

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, turns out I was passing in an int instead of a String in the select item

Comment: In other words, a conversion error has occurred. You would have been notified about this much sooner if you have used `<h:messages>` in the view. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked